# "element.position() is null" error needs solving

Tags: jquery, html, console

I am receiving a

```
Error: element.position() is null
Source File: http://nothingcantouchme.com/js/fGallery.jquery.js
Line: 20
```

on this site: http://nothingcantouchme.com

Can someone kindly assist me in identifying and solving this error? It is causing issues for my Fancybox popup I have written for the trailer. I am sure that I have made a mistake in the index file somewhere as I assure you that the fgallery.jquery.js file is not the issue...

EDIT: Noticed that this error causes problems with most of my jquery scripts and not just the Fancybox one.

Comment: Rather than putting a link to an external site, you should include relevant pieces of code in your question.  Please don't include large files in their entirety, just the relevant pieces.

Comment: @AleksG I honestly do not know which part of the code I should include or so I would have. Although I can see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

There is not style property called 'top'. So, try removing below line from fGallery.jquery.js.

```
clone.css('top', element.position().top);
```

Instead if required you can add below line instead

```
clone.css('vertical-align', 'top');
```

Comment: I have added your adjustment but the error is still there. Thank you for the respond though. Do you have any other ideas? As I said, I believe the error is in relation to what I execute in the index page, and not in the js file...

Comment: Error is inside js file. As I saw http://nothingcantouchme.com/ change is not added. "clone.css('top', element.position().top);" is still in the file.

Comment: Maybe it was cached for you? I double checked and it is updated accordingly.