# 'position().top' is null or not an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, visual-studio

I have the code that should highlight a selection and align the popup to the top of the selection. The code is as follows

```
$('#pnlAdd .modalDialog').css($("tr [style*=Blue]").position().top + "px" ,"top");
```

Firefox seem to be ok with the code, but I get the following runtime error

```
'position().top' is null or not an object.
```

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821026/element-position-is-null-error-needs-solving) but my edit was unsuccessful. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: I am sure `$("tr [style*=Blue]")` must be returning empty set. Can check its length?

Comment: Can you provide an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)?

Comment: $(element).position() can indeed be null/undefined in some cases. I don't think you provided enough context information. Maybe step-through or output to console to see if that `tr [style*=Blue]` returns anything (`.length > 0`). See what happens if you remove the space char after the "tr".

Comment: $("tr [style*=Blue]") length is 0...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .css() arguments are backwards; it should be `.css(<name of property>, <value>)`

```
$('#pnlAdd .modalDialog').css("top", $("tr [style*=Blue]").position().top + "px");
```

Also, `.position()` will return null if `$("tr [style*=Blue]")` doesn't return anything, causing an error. Try checking its length first.

```
var elements = $("tr [style*=Blue]");
if (elements.length) {
    $('#pnlAdd .modalDialog').css("top", elements.position().top + "px");
}
```

**EDIT NOTE**
Firefox use initial caps on the colors (Blue) but IE use all lowercase (blue).

Comment: This did lead me in the right direction, but I have a style "Blue" in Firefox, and "blue" in IE. Thanks for the help!